# ListView with column on the right on a Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

i have a problem with a ListView and i have no idea how to solve it without hardcoding a width:

I have this listView:

```
<ListView 
        Name="lstStates"
        CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True" 
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="lstStates_ItemClick"
        ItemsSource="{Binding States}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="8" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock 
                        CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                        Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding State, FallbackValue=State}"/>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding Count, FallbackValue=1}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see, is basically how the count in the right (the textblock bound with count). The problem is that each grid only uses the width it needs instead of getting the whole space

Ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

Inside the `<ListView></ListView>` tag, add following:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```